# how do i extract the string 'myUIBean' from the string 'com.test.pkg1.myUIBean.getName'

Tags: regex, split

how do i extract the string '**myUIBean**' from the string '**com.test.pkg1.myUIBean.getName**'.
I have a file containing a set of similar strings

```
com.test.pkg1.myUIBean1.getName
com.test.pkg1.myUIBean2.getName
com.test.pkg1.myUIBean3.getName
```

I want the output to be : myUIBean1 myUIBean2 myUIBean3

I am using pattern and displaying the groups extracted but it is selecting all the text before 'myUIBean' in the last sentence. Pattern i am using is : `(.*)"+"UIBean"+"(.*)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `myUIBean\d+`. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gG3bP0/1) OR if `my` is dynamic then try `.*\.(.*UIBean\d+)` and get the first matched group. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gG3bP0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.*\.(myUIBean.*)\..*
```

Assuming you are using java, so you could use the following:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.(myUIBean.*)\\..*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("com.test.pkg1.myUIBean1.getName");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```